# Seeing how long an app was used over the life of the device

Tags: applications, history

I was wondering if there's any way to tell how long a specific app was used over the lifetime of a device?

Just to clarify, I'm not looking to be able to track how long it's used from here on in (although that would be cool too), but rather if there's a way to see how long an app has been used in the past.

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to know how much time a user spends in an app, e.g.: User Bob has used App X for Y hours, then no, there is no way to know that information.

Comment: @CzarMatt Ok, thanks. I assumed as much, figured it couldn't hurt to ask though.